# Is replying to client before receiving complete request allowed for HTTP 1.0 server?

Tags: http, google-chrome, post, boost, xmlhttprequest

I couldn't find RFC that may answer this question. Perhaps you guys can point me to right direction.

I'm implementing strippeddown http server whose only function is to accept big multi-part encoded uploads.

In certain cases, such as file is too big or client is not authorized to upload, I want server to reply with error and close connection immediately.

It looks like Chrome browser doesn't like it because it thinks server returned http code zero.

```
Could not get any response

This seems to be like an error connecting to http://my_ubuntu:8080/api/upload. The response status was 0.
Check out the W3C XMLHttpRequest Level 2 spec for more details about when this happens.
```

Therefore question:

Is replying to client before receiving complete request allowed for HTTP server ?

**update**: Just tested it with iOS 6 client. Same thing, it thinks server abruptly closed connection :(

Comment: Interesting question. I couldn't find anywhere where this was specifically disallowed. However, your life would probably be much simpler if you wrote an **HTTP/1.1** server as you'd have access to the `Expect` header and `100 Continue` responses. That's exactly the situation they're intended to address. I mean, HTTP/1.1 became official in **1994** ... I'd say it's time to upgrade.

Comment: @rdlowrey Yes, I'm considering that now. I just hoped I can implement drop-in replacement of existing PHP-based service without changing clients (which are iOS, Android and Flash).

Comment: Well, I've just recently implemented a 1.1 client myself (not for the device environments you listed or I'd share) and I can say it's not really THAT much more difficult. However, I would expect those environments to already have thoroughly vetted libraries to handle the client side for you.

Comment: It is ok to reply with the error immediately (at least, that is what Squid does), but closing the connection immediately is less common (manage.py runserver maybe?).

Comment: Not an answer but it might be the right direction for one, since it looks like you're using XMLHttpRequest? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Submitting_forms_and_uploading_files

Answer (score 1):

This is a great question and apparently it is very ambiguous. You will probably enjoy reading this article on the "Million Dollar Bug" - http://jacquesmattheij.com/the-several-million-dollar-bug

Answer (score 0):

I think this is certificate trust issue. Try manually trusting the site and subsequent requests should work.